# How can a record belong_to a single user, but also have multiple "secondary" users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

In my app, I have a User model and a Project model. A user has_many assignments and each project belongs_to a user. But along with each project having an owner, the user who created it, I would like the owner be able to share it with others (so that the project gets shown on the other users' account along with their own). I imagine having to use has_many :through, and setting up a projects_users table with a user_id and a project_id. And I guess this would be the end result?

```
Project.first.user
  # The creator of the project
  => #<User id: 1, name: 'andrew', etc...>

Project.first.users
  # The users that the creator chose to share it with
  => [#<User id: 2 ...>, #<User id: 3 ...>]
```

I've been working on this a bit, and I created a SharedProject model with a user_id and project_id column:

```
class SharedProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I would like to call both user.projects and user.shared_projects, but I don't know how I would get shared_projects to return project records instead of records from the shared_projects table. I can't do `has_many :projects, :through => :shared_projects` since then I wouldn't be able to return projects that the user has created.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects # Calling user.projects returns the projects that user created
  has_many :shared_projects # How to get user.shared_projects to return project records?
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can add an owner field to your `Project` model and then and owned projects collection to your `User` model.  You can use what you already have for the shared projects part.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_projects, :class_name => 'Project', :foreign_key => 'owner_id'
end
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

You'll need to add an `owner_id` column to your `projects` table.

Answer (score 0):

Just of the top of my head, I think you might want to set up a ProjectShare model.
The ProjectShare model will belong_to user (the sharer), belong_to project (the project being shared) and has_many user_shared_with (just a different classname for user model)

This way you could see who exactly has shared what with who.
I think you'd could accomplish the same thing with the has_many :through situation by just naming your models accordingly.